# Custom title bar still shows original on startup

Tags: android, android-layout, titlebar

I'm using a custom title bar in my app and it all works fine except that when the app starts up, the original (standard) android title bar is shown for a brief time before it is replaced by my custom title bar.

This is not a problem when the app is already loaded in memory because the 'delay' is not apparent but if the app is not already in memory, it is very obvious.

There's nothing special about the code :

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);
```

I thought about changing the style to have no window title and just include my custom title in the top of the layout but that doesn't seem right.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: If you're talking about on the emulator, it's notoriously slow. Have you tried it on a phone yet?

Comment: Yep. I see this behaviour on the phone. I've just tried changing my theme to have no Window title and <include>'d my title layout in the main layout. Works a treat but is this **really** the right way to do it?  Any downsides to this approach?

Comment: I'm not sure, i remove the title bar in mine but have no custom title bar yet.

Answer (score 1):

[Thomas Devaux](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-custom-window-title-in-android/) has posted a smart solution. It worked in my app

> Change the windowTitleBackgroundStyle to use color “@android:color/transparent”.
>   Also create a style for the text “android:windowTitleStyle” and set its “android:textColor” >to transparent as well.

Comment: You should copy the relevant portions of the link into this answer, otherwise when that link dies, your answer becomes useless.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness to Lluis' answer, here's the full code you need to hide the default-title before the custom-title is initiated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="CustomWindowTitleStyle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">50dp</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleStyle</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a splash screen activity before the main activity loads, should have enough time for the next one to load properly

Comment: Thanks but I'd rather not go down this path.  There are plenty of apps out there that seem to use a custom title bar and don't have the issue I'm having.  Plus I find splash screens annoying ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use an app theme to set a custom title globally for your app? [See here](http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/custom-android-window-title/) for a pretty good example. I had a similar problem and i seem to remember going this route fixed it.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that example was really only using styles to change the appearance of the standard title bar.  My custom title bar has its own layout which I don't think you can define using styles.

Comment: I just remembered what I did for my app.  I used both my custom theme mentioned above and also your original custom title solution.  My app theme styles the title bar to the correct size and color to match the "real" custom title bar that eventually gets loaded.  It's significantly less jarring than having that silly little grey thing show up for 2 seconds during app startup.