# How to use two Themes?

Tags: java, android, xml, themes, android-manifest

I want to use a custom Theme and I want to use the Holo.Light Theme. But I always get the error:

```
Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: 
           You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
```

Currently I'm trying this:

styles.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">55dip</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>
```

It has problems with the:

```
parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
```

in the styles.xml, because if I change it to:

```
parent="android:style/Theme"
```

then it works...

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know where the problem was, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135663/custom-title-bar-still-shows-original-on-startup) solved it:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">55dip</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
</resources>
```